# C#: Custom time zone format strings

Tags: c#, dicom

I need to read the timezone offset from UTC from a custom format. This is defined per standard as:

- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.12.html#sect_C.12.1.1.8

> Encoded as an ASCII string in the format "&ZZXX". The components of
> this string, from left to right, are & = "+" or "-", and ZZ = Hours
> and XX = Minutes of offset. Leading space characters shall not be
> present.
>
> The offset for UTC shall be +0000; -0000 shall not be used.

I fail to understand how I can use any of the modifiers in my case to read this format (and only this format):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

So far I have:

```
bool isValidTimezoneOffsetFromUTC(string timezoneOffsetFromUTC)
{
    try
    {
        DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(timezoneOffsetFromUTC, "%K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (timezoneOffsetFromUTC.Length != 5 || timezoneOffsetFromUTC == "-0000") return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {

    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Which seems overly complex...is there a way to simplify this code without external dependencies ?

Comment: This code is either using the wrong format or the wrong type.  What is the *actual* input string? It can't be just 5 characters. `DateTimeOffset` is a *full* DateTime plus a timezone offset. `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` can be used to parse the full string, not just the offset.

Comment: The offset is specified as a `TimeSpan`, so the correct method to parse an offset is `TimeSpan.ParseExact`, not `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+0000` is an offset, not full datetime and timezone offset. As the name explains, `DateTimeOffset` is used for a full datetime with offset. A valid value would be `2021-09-06T 15:36:49 +00:00` or `2021-09-06T15:36:49+00:00`, not just `+00:00`

The type used to specify offsets is [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0). Parsing a custom timespan format is done using [TimeSpan.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-5.0). The method [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) is used to parse *without* throwing :

```
var input="-0430";
var formats=new[]{"\\+hhmm","\\-hhmm"};
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input,
                                 formats, 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 out var result));
-----
True
```

This method returns `true` if the value is valid. The parsed value is returned through the `result` output parameter.

`TimeSpan.ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` don't parse negative timestamps, so two different formats are used, one for positive and one for negative offsets. In these formats the sign is used as a literal character that must appear in the input.

The method can be rewritten as:

```
const string[] formats=new[]{"\\+hhmm","\\-hhmm"};

bool isValidTimezoneOffsetFromUTC(string timezoneOffsetFromUTC)
{
return TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timezoneOffsetFromUTC,
              formats,
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
              out var result);
}
```

**Update**

Discarding `-0000` only needs a simple equality check :

```
static readonly string[] formats=new[]{"\\+hhmm","\\-hhmm"};

bool isValidTimezoneOffsetFromUTC(string offset)
{
    if (offset=="-0000")
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return TimeSpan.TryParseExact(s,
              formats,
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
              out var result);
}
```

Using pattern matching this can become an expression-bodied method :

```
static readonly string[] formats=new[]{"\\+hhmm","\\-hhmm"};

bool isValidDicomOffset(string offset)=>
    offset switch 
    {
       "-0000"=>false,
       string s=> TimeSpan.TryParseExact(offset,
                      formats,
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                      out var result)
    };
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `HH` isn't a valid [custom TimeSpan format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings). I tried `HH` fist and was surprised when it threw. A `TimeSpan` isn't a time of day so `14` is a valid hour value

Comment: There is an issue with `var input="-0000";` in your code, but is easier to read, thanks !

Comment: @malat what issue? `-0000` works and returns `True`. `00:00` is a valid offset - that's the UK offset during winter

Comment: Well DICOM specification states: `The offset for UTC shall be +0000; -0000 shall not be used.`

Comment: @malat in that case you can add an equality check before parsing. I added it