# Parsing DateTime with/without time zone information

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, dicom

I am trying to implement the DICOM specification for parsing of DateTime. The standard [specify](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_6.2.html#para_2b9600da-017c-4dec-a8aa-7706b50cf771) that:

> A concatenated date-time character string in the format:
>
> YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.FFFFFF&ZZXX
>
> The components of this string, from left to right, are YYYY = Year, MM = Month, DD = Day, HH = Hour (range "00" - "23"), MM = Minute (range "00" - "59"), SS = Second (range "00" - "60").
>
> FFFFFF = Fractional Second contains a fractional part of a second as small as 1 millionth of a second (range "000000" - "999999").
>
> &ZZXX is an optional suffix for offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), where & = "+" or "-", and ZZ = Hours and XX = Minutes of offset.

So far all I could come up with is

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss.FFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I've successfully tested it with:

```
var dateTimeValueStr = "20010301125745.490000";
```

and

```
var dateTimeValueStr = "20010301125745";
```

However I cannot understand the documentation on how to implement parsing of the optional suffix for the offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It seems ['zzz'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#offset-z-format-specifier) only works with an explicit colon sign ':'. And I cannot use something like `"\\+hhmm"`, since there would be multiple 'h' pattern in the same format string.

Q:

Is there a way to read this DICOM DateTime with a single call to `DateTime.ParseExact` ? Or do I need a separate call to `DateTime.ParseExact` for reading the DateTime (no timezone) and then a second call to `TimeSpan.ParseExact` to parse the timezone info ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69076802/c-custom-time-zone-format-strings)).

Typical example:

```
var dateTimeValueStr = "20010301125745.490000-0500";
```

Comment: The type that includes an offset is `DateTimeOffset`, not `DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try providing *several formats* in one `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
  static DateTime MyParse(string value) => DateTime.ParseExact(
    value, 
    new string[] { 
      "yyyyMMddHHmmss.FFFFFF", 
      "yyyyMMddHHmmss.FFFFFFzzz",
    },
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "20010301125745.490000",
    "20010301125745.490000-0500",
    "20010301125745.490000+0000",
    "20010301125745.490000-0000",
    "20010301125745.490000+0700",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,30} => {MyParse(test):yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
     20010301125745.490000 => 2001-03-01 12:57:45
20010301125745.490000-0500 => 2001-03-01 17:57:45
20010301125745.490000+0000 => 2001-03-01 12:57:45
20010301125745.490000-0000 => 2001-03-01 12:57:45
20010301125745.490000+0700 => 2001-03-01 05:57:45
```

Comment: It's actually insane that I can `ParseExact` time zone info `"+0000"` using `zzz`, but I cannot `ToString` + `zzz` without an explicit colon sign...of well.